# Want to set more than one color to a method setBackgroundColor()

Tags: java, graphics2d

I need one small advice on how to set more than one colour to a method setBackgroundColor, i managed to make more than one color but only if program randomly pick color but i want to set specific 4 or five colours,here is my part of the code:
(so on selected object it changes color)

```
if (isSelected)
    style.setBackgroundColor (new Color ((float) Math.random(),
                                         (float) Math.random(),
                                         (float) Math.random()));
  else
    style.unsetBackgroundColor();
```

Comment: How would you set more than one background colour?  Which colour would actually be the used as the background colour?

Comment: to explain it is not actually a backgroundcolor of whole frame it it just  a background color of one object that shows on frame and if i click on that object it should change color of that object.that's why i need more than one colour so that i could change it on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want 4 or 5 specific colors what you could do is make a list.

```
ArrayList<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<Color>();
//Then you add any colors you want, although you would have to define them yourself.
colorList.add(color1);
```

After adding the colors to a color list, you would need a way to grab a random color. One way we could do this is by making a Random object and using it to find an Integer from 0 to the list's size.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int colorNum = rand.nextInt(colorList.size());
```

Now that we have the actual number, we can simply access that index in the list.

```
Color c = colorList.get(colorNum);
//Now, assuming your code above works for one color, you could do your 
style.setBackgroundColor(c);
```

This way you can add any colors in or even make colors based on user request and it would handle any color as long as you add it to the list.